# JS: keyEvents won't work correctly - work with +1 key(press-down-up)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, key-events

I have a problem. I need to catch changes in input text form and refresh result div, but when I entering "12" I see result for "1", when I entering "123" I see result for "12". What to do?

```
 var securityID = genSecurityID();

 $(document).on('keypress', '#poisk', function () {
     //$(document).on('change', '#poisk', function(){
     var poisk_val = $(this).val();
     //alert(poisk_val);
     //$('#poisk').keydown(function(){ 
     //$(this).keydown(function(){ 
     var data1 = {
         'search': poisk_val,
         '_': securityID
     };
     AjaxResultat(data1, 'search', '.search_res', '?view=live_search');
     //alert(poisk_val);
     //});
 });
```

Comment: Change `keypress` to `keyup`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle a keyup event instead of a keypress.

Comment: I don't understand, I already tried this, but it doesn't work, but now it's works perfectly! why? O_o